# Pagination - what it is and how to do it

Tags: pagination

I want the pagination  below . Can you help me !

**First | Previous | Page 2 of 5 | Next | Last**

Pagination - what it is and how to do it

Comment: You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that. In memory or not.

In memory is when your list is big enough to mess the UI, but not big enough to mess your server memory allocation (data x users > available memory). This is easier to implement but does not solve all the problems.

Not in memory is when your list is too big to fit in memory or it's too big so it compromises your application, speed, etc. In this case, you usually will query this data from a backend database using 2 parameters: the index of the first record and the offset (or page size). In this way, you're going to retrieve just a small amount of data, leaving the sorting/filtering heavyweight task to the database (which is pretty good in this kind of thing)

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is used when you can have a large data set to return that you don't want to display all of it but chunk it into pages.

For example if you have a sql query that returned 10,000 rows but you only wanted to show 100 of them you would paginate them.  ( those links you have above would be a reference to the page number of the result set you would want to return.

Then for your sql you can adjust the LIMIT in the query based on the page # . Hope this helps .